# Any progress on Plots of Quantities?

Tags: plotting, units

Plots of quantities still don't seem to work. I've implemented the one suggestion people have: use `Evaluate`, but now the values of my plots are just completely off and I don't know if it's a `LogPlot`, `Erfc`, or `Quantity` issue. Here's a MWE:

Run these two snippets as cells:

```
CS = Quantity[1*^21, 1/("Centimeters")^3]
cs = CS;
zu = Quantity[0.000026410791763405103`, "Centimeters"]
Cv[z_] := cs Erfc[z/zu]
Evaluate[Cv[10 zu]]
LogPlot[Evaluate@Cv[z], {z, 0 zu, 10 zu}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image: Output of Above Code: Failure of Quantities]

```
cs = 1.1*^21
zu = 0.0000264108
Evaluate[Cv[10 zu]]
LogPlot[Evaluate@Cv[z], {z, 0 zu, 10 zu}, AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image: Output of above code: Success of Bare Numbers]

and you'll see a marked difference in the plots. I have no idea why Mathematica would have an issue with this. I'd also really prefer not to resort to a dimensionalized x-axis, since the units of the x-axis are important to presenting the relationship here.